# L'Hospital's rule for analytic functions of complex variable

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Is there L'Hospital's rule for analytic functions of complex variable?

If yes where can I find it, in what books, and how to prove it?

Comment: Yes, most basic complex variables books should have a proof. It's similar to the proof for real variables, using the definition of the derivative.

Comment: Here's a link:  https://books.google.com/books?id=KaYuyybIqnMC&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=l%27hopital%27s+rule+for+analytic+functions+proof&source=bl&ots=K-KvWtkgT8&sig=i5UW2DEvbD_645uNgH4C7aQ2ZB4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lCduVaTzLcS0ogTDx4HQAQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=l'hopital's%20rule%20for%20analytic%20functions%20proof&f=false